# Ruby MLT implementation / examples?

Tags: ruby

On the project web page:

http://www.mltframework.org/bin/view/MLT/Features

MLT says it has language bindings for ruby, I looking for some code examples, or tutorials utilizing the MLT library in ruby.

Comment: It's MLT, not MTL, according to the page you've linked to.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of example ruby scripts [here](https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/tree/master/src/swig/ruby). They're fairly basic but should provide a starting point.